# Cannot boot Ubuntu 14.04 USB on different computers, blinking cursor kill screen

Tags: 14.04, boot, usb, dell, hp

I have been having a problem involving attempting to boot Ubuntu 14.04 on some computers. I installed Ubuntu onto a USB using my home HP Pavilion Quad-Core, and the computer I am trying to make the OS run on is a Dell... All I know about it is that it is Dell, at the time being. From previous chats with a person who supposedly knows what they're doing, it should work on both computers. I'm thinking that the problem has to do with UFEI and Legacy booting, of which the HP is UFEI and the Dell is Legacy. I have tried every fix I could find on google and on these forums, and I have found nothing that helped. Can anybody help me with the limited information I have provided?